# Is it possible to exectue a function on model delete?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model Stock and DeltaStock.

```py
class Stock(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField()

class DeltaStock(models.Model):
    delta_quantity = models.DecimalField()
    stock = models.ForeignKey(to=Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Stock is the state of the warehouse with the current state. And everytime something is taken out of the stock, I subtract that from the quantity and create `DeltaStock`. But if something gets returned to the stock i want to delete `DeltaStock` and add that quantity back to the stock. So my question is: Is there a way to execute a function that adds `delta_quantity` when `DeltaStock` gets deleted? I should be executed no matter which way `DeltaStock` gets deleted.

Comment: "But if something gets returned to the stock i want to delete DeltaStock and add that quantity back to the stock." Are you sure? Shouldn't you just create another, inverse, delta stock? Deleting events sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: Yes, i agree usually it is. But here it is not exactly an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, what you're looking for are so called **signals** - in this instance specifically you would want to use `pre_delete` or `post_delete` - depending on your needs.

I won't bother going into detail here, as the official documentation on this is very intuitive and thorough.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/

Comment: Signals will not be fired with e.g. bulk deletes, though.

Comment: @AKX Bulk deletes were not mentioned by the person asking

Comment: I'm aware, but it's also something that's good to know.

Comment: @AKX you're right, but taking this into account complicates matters quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for. I am just wondering why wouldn't this work with bulk deletes?

Comment: @urboom well, imagine bulk-deleting a huge number of rows from your database, let's say 1.000.000. Now imagine having the server run 1.000.000 functions - because that's what those 'signals' trigger at the end of the day - at once. Could become quite problematic for the server.

Comment: Oh, i see. Yes it's probably not the best scenario. But fortunately i don't need to use bulk delete in my case. Thanks for info

Comment: Actually I'm usually try to prevent using signals. I wrote [an article](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html) about the problems with signals. While signals are sometimes necessary, for example for a 3rd party app, I would advise to look at the views that might delete an object, and thus encapsulate the logic in a function, and call that function in those views.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for the advice - I've read an article from your site before and remember it being very well written. I'll have a look over it.